# C# Run command prompt from resources

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, cmd, resources, embedded-resource

I have a file that i need to run by creating a command prompt.
Basically this is how it goes:

The file's name is UArtCMD.exe, i use it by opening a command prompt in it's directory and run commands that are programmed into it, for example "uartcmd a". What i'm trying to do is add a gui to this software externally, and when, let's say, a button is pressed on the gui, it will run a command using the command prompt.

I've managed to make it run off my computer without any hitches, but the problems occur occur when i install the software on a different computer. Because the UArtCMD is an external software, it wont be on every computer, so what i tried doing is adding it to the resources of the project and run it from there, the problem is i have no idea how to do so.

This is my code for running the command prompt on the computer which has the UArtCMD

```
public static string executeLine(string command)
    {
        string result;
        try
        {
            Process process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + command)
            {
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                WorkingDirectory = "C:\\UArtCMD",
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true
            });
            process.WaitForExit();
            string text = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            process.Close();
            MainWindow.log(text);
            result = text;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = ex.StackTrace;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

If you need me to add any info or expand more on the question do let me know i will gladly do so.

Comment: 1) where do you extract from resources and save your executable on file system? 2) I wouldn't use c:\something as working directory (users with restrictions or UAC may prevent this)

Comment: Remove the WorkingDirectory attribute, add uARTCMD as part of your project, and chage it to "Copy local"

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I dont extract them, they are in the resources, and i've set the "Copy to Output Directory" property to "Always" like SalamiArmy suggested

Answer (score 0):

1. Include a reference to the file UArtCMD.exe in your solution (can be anywhere in the solution structure).
2. Set its "Copy to Output Directory" property to "Always".
3. Set your process' "WorkingDirectory" property to
   "Environment.CurrentDirectory".

Now UArtCMD.exe should always find it's way into the bin directory (even if it's built by a build agent into a strange output directory) and the code will know to look for it in the same directory as the code is running from.

Edit: The comment about removing the "WorkingDirectory" property from your process object is valid, you can do that instead of setting it to "Environment.CurrentDirectory", they both do the same thing.

Comment: it works when it's on my visual studio, but when i publish it and use the setup.exe on another computer it wont work, it opens the command prompt at some weird place: "C:\Users\amitl\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\CDX6CCR1.79G\5WDJ5DCZ.62Y\rts...tion_5f66aa7ae274c4f6_0001.0000_826a6715465111b8\UArtCMD"

Comment: If you are having problems with not setting the "WorkingDirectory" property or setting it to Environment.CurrentDirectory there is a more thorough way. Try setting it to: (new System.Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)).AbsolutePath

Comment: Infact "(new System.Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)).AbsolutePath" will include the running assembly file name. You really want the containing directory. "Path.GetDirectoryName" can resolve that for you. So the full expression to assign to WorkingDirectory is like:

**Path.GetDirectoryName((new System.Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)).AbsolutePath)**

If you really want to be thorough about finding UArtCMD.exe relative to the running assembly.